# can we launch more than one instance with chef through knife?

Tags: amazon-ec2, chef-infra, chef-recipe, knife

knife ec2 server create doesn't have anything to support this functionality.
I want to launch 4 instances and push the recipes at the time of creation only.

Comment: Just loop over a list of machines and launch knife 4 times ? (or have a look at chef-provision or terraform)

Comment: loop over as in??

Comment: like in bash `for (s in "srv1 srv2 srv3 srv4") do; knife ec2 server create $s ....; done` But read coderanger answer, I won't venture further with so few information on the overall goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you just call it 4 times. The knife cloud tools are intentionally simplistic and are really only for very simple toy infras or learning Chef. For managing "real" systems you'll want something more full-featured (and also more complex) like Terraform or CloudFormation/SparkleFormation.